Seeking Advice: Improving Resin Application in Honeycomb Lamination for a Sustainable Project
I am trying to laminate a honeycomb structure with a fiberglass and resin reinforcement. However, I have problems because a large amount of resin falls through the holes of the honeycomb and the final finish is not perfect because due to the holes, the finish is not smooth. Could you recommend me some previous process that can solve these problems?
The project itself is focused to be a sustainable product, so the solution that you can give would be very good that it is of these characteristics.
Thanks in advance
Regards,
Antonio Jimenez

How big? Take a sheet(s) of thick high-rise glass window and then lay your  skin on the glass. Spray and wet the skin. Then when green, apply the correct core bond putty and lay the honeycomb on and lay another plate on top. When cured, flip and repeat. I used to make panels up to 40' long doing this. But you really need to use the right material. Honeycomb is expensive, and the bonding systems require high precision in order to develop the rated strength without excess weight.

If you have a method to remove, you may be able to fill holes and remove after curing. There is a point where epoxy flows well due to heat. If you have the right geometry, you can keep it at that temperature for long enough to let gravity control where it goes.
